# Mathematica Online & WolframAlpha Notebook Edition

Tags: mathematica-online

My college provides a site license to Mathematica, including access to Mathematica Online. I daily use a notebook I created long ago, and it always works as expected.

I just opened a new file, and noticed for the first time that the header of my web page is Wolfram|Alpha Notebook Edition. And I *cannot* enter anything as `InputForm`, only the Wolfram|Alpha "Natural Language" Input, or version of text (and, oddly, `Output`). See screenshot:

[image]

My fundamental question is "What is going on!!?? What happened to Mathematica Online?" Is this an issue where my school is now paying for a different service, or did Mathematica Online completely go away? Is there a way to access `InputForm`?

This seems to be a different issue than the downloaded, installed version of Notebook Edition. With that program, there seems to be a way to change the back end; see [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/223703/change-default-cell-type-of-wolframalpha-notebook-edition-to-input). That solution doesn't apply to the cloud version.

Comment: This seems like a question that might best be answered by WRI support (support@wolfram.com)

Comment: Or, more likely, your school's sysadmin office who should know what their license covers and how the system is configured.

Comment: I have an email out to our Wolfram rep about the issue. Figured I’d reach out here, too, in case someone knows the answer,  or if others have this problem in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and got in touch with Wolfram Support. Somehow, my Theme option (Preferences > General > Theme) was set to Wolfram|Alpha Notebook Edition. Setting it back to Wolfram Mathematica fixed the issue.

Comment: Thanks - I checked and the only option I see is Notebook Edition. Not sure why I can't choose something else. Have reached out to Wolfram Support on this, too. Still waiting.