# What's the difference between Mathematica 14 and Wolfram Alpha Notebook 14

Tags: replacement

A version of my question was asked in 2019 ([What is the difference between Mathematica and WolframAlpha Notebook Edition?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/206162/what-is-the-difference-between-mathematica-and-wolframalpha-notebook-edition)) with no clear answer then.  Is there anything new that that addresses this?  Specifically, is there anything that Wolfram Alpha Notebook can do that Mathematica cannot do or anything Mathematica can do that Wolfram Alpha Notebook cannot do?  I opened a few of my notebooks in both programs.  Except for minor cosmetic differences, I didn't encounter any problems with either program executing the notebook functions.  The old 2019 answer focused on free-form questions in Wolfram Alpha Notebook.  But as far as I can tell, that same functionality is in Mathematica now.  Is there anything in a notebook that one of the two cannot execute?